# Problem with Firestore Timestamp and Google Cloud Functions (date.toDate() is not a function)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am getting a date (from firestore) in a cloud function, and then returning it to the client side.

This is the resulted date object:

```
Object {
   "_nanoseconds": 1607618708,
   "_seconds": 615000000,
} // I know how to convert this to a javascript date object, but I need the .toDate()
```

Then, in the frontend, **if I execute date.toDate() I get the error ".toDate is not a function".**

In the other hand, if I get the same date from the client directly, all works perfectly... (.toDate() is a function)

This is the resulted date object:

```
t {
    "nanoseconds": 1607618708,
    "seconds": 615000000,
}
```

What is happening here? How can I solve this problem?

### UPDATE

-> Code which doesn't work:

```
// Cloud Function
var userData = await firebase.getUserData(userId); // userRef.get().then(doc => ... return doc.data());
console.log(userData.birthday);
/*
    Timestamp {
       _seconds: 1038832012,
       _nanoseconds: 14000000 
    }
*/


return { userData }

// Client side

firebase.functions.httpsCallable(...)(...).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data.userData.birthday);
    /*
        Object {
           "_nanoseconds": 1607618708,
           "_seconds": 615000000,
        }

        new Date(date._seconds * 1000) will work but I need to execute .toDate()
    */
    const birthday = res.data.userData.birthday.toDate();
    // ERROR: .toDate is undefined
})...
```

-> Code which works (no server side):

```
 // Client side 
 const userData = await userRef.get().then((doc) => ... return doc.data());
 console.log(userData.birthday);
 /*
    t {
        "nanoseconds": 1607618708,
        "seconds": 615000000,
     } 
 */
 const birthday = userData.birthday.toDate(); // WORKS GOOD
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect, both frontend and backend.

Comment: @DougStevenson done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callable functions only serialize objects to JSON.  When the SDK serializes a Timestamp, it merely takes its fields and constructs a new JSON object out of it.  That object has no formal type.  It is just a plain object with the two fields of data - seconds and nanoseconds - that it found inside the object.

The client is going to receive that JSON with the two fields, but not necessarily know that it came from a Timestamp.  You will have to write code on the client app to convert that JSON object with seconds and nanos back into a Timestamp, if that's what it want to use.  Once you have seconds and nanos, you can simply create a new Timestamp with its [constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#constructor) (`new Timestamp(seconds, nanos)`).  Then you can call `toDate()` on that Timestamp.  There is really no shortcut for this, except for you provide for yourself.

Comment: hey Doug. I am running into this issue - and keep getting the following error: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _firebase.default.Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds)')]

Do you have a fix or know why I am unable to create a new timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
if(userData.birthday.toString.contains('_seconds'){
return Timestamp(userData.birthday['_seconds'], userData.birthday['_nanoseconds']);
}else{
return Timestamp(userData.birthday);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp can be converted to date on the server and sent to client.

For example: inside api route:

```
const collectionRef = db.collection("users")
  const snapshot = await collectionRef.get();
  const users = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    const data = doc.data();
    return {
      id: doc.id,
      ...data,
      updatedAt: data.updatedAt.toDate(),
      appointmentAt: data.appointmentAt.toDate(),
    };
  });
```

send users to clinet